# magento gives error while creating form

Tags: magento

I want to build a form. I tried a lot with below code but it always gives me error.

Error:

```
2015-08-03T08:49:26+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form::setForm() must be an instance of Varien_Data_Form, instance of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentobigcom\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php on line 315 and defined  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentobigcom\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form.php on line 119
2015-08-03T08:49:26+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract::setRenderer() must implement interface Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface, instance of Sample_Bigcom_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_File given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentobigcom\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php on line 438 and defined  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentobigcom\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Abstract.php on line 164
```

and code is here:

```
<?php
class Sample_Bigcom_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_File extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{


    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
'id' => 'edit_form',
'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/process', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
'method' => 'post',
'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
)
);
             return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

is there any thing which i should write in any config file or system file to get rid of this error?

Can anyone give me some solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the form on $this.

```
protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/process', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        )
    );

    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Furthermore I would recommend using a container (extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container) around the form.

Here are nice tutorials:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/01/module-development-series-magento-admin-module-part3/

http://astrio.net/blog/magento-admin-form/